# Why can't IPython return records with multiple fields when submitting a query to sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, field, ipython

I am trying to write a simple query to an sqlite database in a python script. To test if my parameters were correct, I tried running the query from the ipython command line. It looked something like this:

```
import sqlite3
db = 'G:\path\to\db\file.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
results = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM studies').fetchall()
```

for some reason, my results came back totally empty. Then I tried another test query:

```
results = conn.execute('SELECT id FROM studies').fetchall()
```

Which returned correctly. I figured there was a problem with the asterisk [WRONG, SEE SECOND UPDATE BELOW], so I tried the 'SELECT * FROM studies' query from a default python command line. Lo and behold, it returned correctly. I tried all the normal ways to escape the asterisk only to be met by a wide variety of error messages. Is there any way to run this query in IPython?

---

EDIT: Sorry, I incorrectly assumed IronPython and IPython were the same. What I meant was the IPython command line, not the IronPython framework.

---

EDIT2: Okay, it turns out the asterisk DOES work as shown by this successful query:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM studies'
```

From the suggestions posted here, it turns out the error results from trying to return records with multiple fields, i.e.:

```
'SELECT field1,field2 FROM studies'
```

which still results in to records being returned. I have changed the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL.  IronPython has little or nothing to do with the processing of the query.  Are you using an unusual character encoding? (IE not UTF-8 or ASCII)?

What happens if you `SELECT id,fieldname,fieldname FROM studies` (In other words, simulating what '*' does.)

Comment: Simulating the '*' query also returned nothing. It seems that the query only works when I ask for one field. I tried the  query you suggested in the regular python command line, and I got the correct answer. This leads me to believe that ironpython is doing something a little differently before the sql query is sent.

Comment: If you just run the query at the interpreter prompt, what does it say the return value is?

Answer (score 1):

Some more debugging you could try:

```
s = 'SELEECT * from studies'
print s
conn.execute(s).fetchall()
```

or:

```
s = 'SELECT ' + chr(42) + ' from studies'
conn.execute(s).fetchall()
```

You might also try:

```
conn.execute('select count(*) from studies').fetchall()
```

if that comes back as [(0,)] then something really weird is going on :-)

---

Some more things you could try:

```
conn.execute('select id from (select * from studies)').fetchall()
```

or:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from studies').fetchall()
```

Comment: Your first two suggestions return zero results. :(

'select count(*) from studies' returns the correct amount of rows, so the asterisk character still works correctly. For now, the error only happens with I try to return results with more than one field. i.e.:

    'SELECT field1,field2 FROM studies'

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the things you've mentioned in IPython and sqlite without any problems (ipython 0.9.1, python 2.5.2).

Is there a chance this is some kind of version mismatch issue?  Maybe your shells are referencing different libraries?

For example, does

```
import sqlite3; print sqlite3.version
```

return the same thing from both shells (i.e. ipython and the regular one where the sql query works)?

How about

```
conn.execute('select sqlite_version()').fetchall()
```

Does that return the same thing?

Comment: My version of ipython is also 0.9.1, but I'm using python 2.6.2. Both shells had matching version for both of questions you asked. Specifically, 'sqlite3.version' returned 2.4.1, and 'SELECT sqlite_version()' returned 3.5.9

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but please try to escape backslashes in the path to the database file. In other words instead of

```
db = 'G:\path\to\db\file.sqlite'
```

try

```
db = 'G:\\path\\to\\db\\file.sqlite'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found the only way to get the correct output was by assigning the results of the execute statement to another cursor object and calling fetchall on that:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3
In [2]: conn = sqlite3.connect('file.db')
In [3]: cur = conn.cursor()
In [4]: cur2 = cur.execute("<STATEMENT>")
In [5]: cur2.fetchall()
```